# Handlebars: Lexical error due to white space that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

i'm getting a strange error when attempting to compile my template in Handlebars.

I simply ajax in the templates HTML, and then trim the result to make sure there are no whitespaces, however this shouldn't cause an issue anyway.

This is my template within slider.hbs:

```
<div class="review-cards__title">
    <img src="/img-src/themev2/theme/{{toLowerCase website.source }}-logo.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="slick-slider">
    {{#each reviews }}
        <div class="review-card">
            <div class="review-card__name">{{ name }}</div>
            <div class="review-card__quote">
                {{ quote }}
            </div>
            <div class="review-card__stars">
                {{#rating-star rating }}
                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {{/rating-star}}
                {{#rating-empty rating 5 }}
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {{/rating-empty}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="stats">
    {{#ifEquals website.source "JudgeService" }}
        {{#if judgeservice.dealer_id }}
            {{#if judgeservice.dealer_name }}
                <div id="js-widget-button">
                    <a href="https://www.judgeservice.com/en-gb/car-dealership/name/{{nospace judgeservice.dealer_name }}/" target="_blank" title="{{ judgeservice.dealer_name }} - reviewed on JudgeService.com">
                        {{ judgeservice.dealer_name }} - reviewed on JudgeService.com
                    </a>
                </div>
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/ifEquals}}
    <p>Provided By {{ website.source }}</p>
</div>
```

Then I request the data and send it to another method:

```
 self.xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                self.outputData.call(self, self.xhttp.responseText);
            }
```

And then of course I try and compile the HTML:

```
outputData(templateHTML) {
        const self = this;

        templateHTML = templateHTML.trim();
        console.log(templateHTML);

        let templateScript = Handlebars.compile(templateHTML);
        let html = templateScript(self.context);
```

This is the error i'm getting, I really don't understand what i'm doing wrong here!
[image]

**Edit:**

I assign the helpers before I run the aJax calls to fetch the templates.

Below is my entire aJax call, the entire script works fine if use the global template (they are identical) from the `themev2` folder rather than the `self.context["website"]["code"]` folder.

```
getTemplate() {

        const self = this;

        self.xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            // Dealer has template
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                self.outputData.call(self, self.xhttp.responseText);
            }

            // Check for global template
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 404) {

                self.xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                        self.outputData.call(self, self.xhttp.responseText);
                        return;
                    } else if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 404) {
                        self.outputData.call(self, null);
                    }
                };
                self.xhttp.open("GET", "/templates/themev2/reviews/panel/" + self.template + ".hbs", true);
                self.xhttp.send();

            }
        };

        self.xhttp.open("GET", "/templates/" + self.context["website"]["code"] + "/reviews/panel/" + self.template + ".hbs", true);
        self.xhttp.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello below is a snippet that is using the same template code as yours and it compiles as expected. I think that you forgot to declare your custom helpers : toLowerCase, ifEquals, rating-star and rating-empty. Define them before you compile otherwise you'll have compilation errors. As I get no error running the same template as you it is not related to the template itself but rather to unresolved references.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  Handlebars.registerHelper('toLowerCase', function (str) {
  if(str && typeof str === "string") {
    return str.toLowerCase();
  }
  return '';
  });
  Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
  });
  Handlebars.registerHelper('rating-star', function(arg1, options) {
    return options.fn(this);
  });
  Handlebars.registerHelper('rating-empty', function(arg1, arg2, options) {
    return options.fn(this);
  });
  var context = { 
    "website" : { "source" : "test" }, 
    "reviews": [ 
      {"name" : "review1","quote" : "review1 quote","rating" : "1"},
      {"name" : "review2","quote" : "review2 quote","rating" : "5"},
      {"name" : "review3","quote" : "review3 quote","rating" : "3"}
    ] 
  };
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="review-cards__title">
    <img src="/img-src/themev2/theme/{{toLowerCase website.source}}-logo.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="slick-slider">
    {{#each reviews }}
        <div class="review-card">
            <div class="review-card__name">{{ name }}</div>
            <div class="review-card__quote">
                {{ quote }}
            </div>
            <div class="review-card__stars">
                {{#rating-star rating }}
                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {{/rating-star}}
                {{#rating-empty rating 5 }}
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {{/rating-empty}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="stats">
    {{#ifEquals website.source "JudgeService" }}
        {{#if judgeservice.dealer_id }}
            {{#if judgeservice.dealer_name }}
                <div id="js-widget-button">
                    <a href="https://www.judgeservice.com/en-gb/car-dealership/name/{{nospace judgeservice.dealer_name }}/" target="_blank" title="{{ judgeservice.dealer_name }} - reviewed on JudgeService.com">
                        {{ judgeservice.dealer_name }} - reviewed on JudgeService.com
                    </a>
                </div>
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/ifEquals}}
    <p>Provided By {{ website.source }}</p>
</div>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response. I do add the helpers however before I assign the templates. And this is definitely working due to it rendering using the global template. It only seems to be an issue when using a custom template. See my updated post

Comment: Did you try to output self.context["website"]["code"] with a console.log to check if the variable is existing also it it exists then do you see in the network panel if the template is downloaded. Try also to compare the two templates from what is sent to the browser.